# A bound tighter than Chebyshev's for finite variance and zero mean

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

The question is: Suppose $EX=0$ and $EX^2=\sigma^2$. Show that
$$
P(X\geq a)\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + a^2}
$$
or equivalently,
$$
EX^2 P(X<a)\geq a^2 P(X\geq a)
$$
I have a proof but it is fairly long for an archived pset and I was hoping to see if there was a shorter proof. Here's an outline of what I have:

(1) Prove the (in)equality for the class of simple $X$ that take the form $$\displaystyle X(s)=\begin{cases}a& (s\in A)\\b&(s\in \Omega \backslash A)\end{cases}$$

(2) Extend the proof to the class of simple $X$ takes the form $$\displaystyle X(s)=\begin{cases}a_1& (s\in A_1)\\\vdots & \\ a_n & (s\in A_n)\\b&(s\in B)\end{cases}$$ where $a\leq a_1 < a_2<\cdots $ and $A_1\sqcup \cdots \sqcup A_n \sqcup B = \Omega$.

That is, allow for $X$ to map to more than one value $\geq a$ but only one value $<a$.

(3) Extend the proof to the class of simple $X$ which maps to two values less than $a$
$$\displaystyle X(s)=\begin{cases}a_1& (s\in A_1)\\\vdots & \\ a_n & (s\in A_n)\\b_1&(s\in B_1)\\
b_2&(s\in B_2)\end{cases}$$
by partitioning $B$ into $B_1$ and $B_2$

(4) The formalities: extend via induction to the class of all simple $X$ and show that this implies the inequality holds for any measurable r.v.